# Change clip in CSS with JS

Tags: javascript, css, clip

So I'm making an HP bar and I need to shorten the width of the HP bar when the remainingHealth is decreasing. So far I've written this.

*JS*

```
var remainingHealth =333;
function update(){
    document.getElementById("nowbar").style.clip = "rect(0, remainingHealth, 90, 0)";
}
```

*CSS*

```
#nowbar {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    clip: rect(0px,666px,90px,0px)
}
```

I created an image to explain what the problem is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgWV8.png

So the problem is that I can't control the width with JS so on the screen the width is showing 666px instead of remainingHealth(333px). But when I change remaininingHealth with 333 in the style.clip it's displaying 333px so it's working.

Comment: There is no automatic replacing of variable names in text literals in JavaScript – you have to properly _build_ the string by concatenating the single parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there is a little confusion in how you are looking at this I think.

So when you write the javascript code:

```
var remainingHealth =333;
```

The var `remainingHealth` does equal 333. It does not equal 666 or is any way connected to the CSS file as you seem to be implying in your pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgWV8.png

The problem is that

```
document.getElementById("nowbar").style.clip
```

requires a string value, you are giving it a string value too, the string value you are setting `document.getElementById("nowbar").style.clip` to is:

```
"rect(0, remainingHealth, 90, 0)"
```

That is the same as if doing in your CSS file:

```
    #nowbar {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    clip: rect(0, remainingHealth, 90, 0);
    }
```

You can see that "remainingHealth" is not valid CSS, remainingHealth is a string in your javascript code is what I am trying to show you, it is not the var remainingHealth that you set to the integer value of 333.

You need to do:

```
document.getElementById("nowbar").style.clip = "rect(0," + remainingHealth + "px, 90, 0)";
```

Javascript is "kind" enough to convert the int var remainingHealth to the string value "333" for your string concatenation.